# How to use SingleEmailMessage.setReferences Method

Tags: email, singleemailmessage

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setReferences), the setReferences function "Identifies an email thread. Contains the parent emails' References and message IDs, and possibly the In-Reply-To fields".

I can't actually find any specific information on how to set this field though.  Is this something specific to Salesforce or is it part of the general email protocol?